# Regex to get specific numbers with three digits

Tags: regex

Im trying to get a string to match this pattern:

```
C006,
C007,
C008,
C009,
C010,
C011
```

I have this:

```
C00[6-9]|1[0-1]
```

And it works with "C006" to "C009", but when I got "C010" or "C011" the regex match only with the number 10 or 11.

Tested on http://rubular.com/r/gFKJ2eTyrz

Can anyone help-me with this?

Thankss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is

```
C00[6-9]
```

or

```
1[0-1]
```

https://regex101.com/r/CsjWzT/3

You need to group the alternative patterns. Try:

```
C0(0[6-9]|1[0-1])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CsjWzT/1

If you want it exact use anchors:

```
^C0(0[6-9]|1[0-1])$
```

https://regex101.com/r/CsjWzT/2

Comment: C0(0[6-9]|1[0-1]) is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot dude!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `C(\d){3}`

C -> matches the char 'C'

\d -> matches any number

{3} -> only three digits

Comment: This will match things that it shouldn't, like `C111`.

Comment: Like Barmar said, it matches some patterns that I dont need. Anyway, thanks for the reply man!